# Connecting a PLM Tool to Tableau using REST API

Tags: tableau-api, rest, tableau-desktop

I am trying to connect data from a PLM tool to Tableau using the REST API. I am not super familiar with the REST API, so I am unsure how to connect it to Tableau Desktop. Is it even possible to connect a REST API to Tableau Desktop? Do I need additional tools to build the connection between the API and Tableau? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to connect REST API to Tableau Desktop. And yes, you'll need additional tools to build the connection.
Steps:

1. Set up an ODBC connection. Visit this website for this step -> https://kb.blackbaud.com/knowledgebase/articles/Article/41081
2. Open Tableau Desktop and under connect to a server, select "Other Databases (ODBC)".
3. Connect and in the "String Extras" box, put in your SDSN, HST, and PRT information.
4. Choose the database that the RESP API is connected to. You can see how to do that in the REST API documentation of the site you're using.
5. Filter the data you want to see in Tableau and you should have your data there.

There are so many ways to make this connection and this is one of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Tableau doesn't support REST API as a data source directly. You have to use indirect ways to connect to REST API.

One way is to use Web Data Connector, BUT you have to build a web page for each REST API and paste the web page link in Web Data Connector. (I did this before and it's pretty crazy...)

Another way is to use an ETL tool that supports extracting data from API and loading it to Tableau. This way saves you lots of time although you need to pay for additional costs. (I personally recommend Acho. Its API connector is very powerful and easy-to-use)